# Perl script with JIRA REST-API to create JIRA along with custom field

Tags: perl, perl-module, jira-rest-api

We are unable to create the new ticket in Jira using REST-API via Perl script.

Note: Without custom field script successfully executing. please provide the suggestion to add a custom field in my script.

**Screenshot for the custom field.**

[image]

**Error Message:**

JIRA::REST Error[400 - Bad Request]:
- [custom_field] Field 'custom_field' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.at copy_of_new-jira.pl line 16.

**Perl Script :**

```
#Loading the modules from a specific location such that JIRA::REST.

    use JIRA::Client::Automated;
    use JIRA::REST;
    use Data::Dumper;

  #Login details about Jira server

    my $jira = JIRA::REST->new({
        url      => 'https://xxxxxxxx.xxxxx.com',
        username => 'xxxxxxx',
        password => 'xxxxxxx',
    });

    # Create the ticket using post function 
    my $issue = $jira->POST('/issue', undef, {
        fields => {
            project   => { key => 'TIME' },
            issuetype => { name => 'Task' },
            summary   => '20-7-2018 checking field persent or not',
            description => 'test',
            custom_field => { Epic Link => 'Application Framework'},
        },
    });
```

Comment: have you tried `custom_field => { 'Epic Link' => 'Application Framework' }`?

Comment: It seems like you're not supposed to put custom fields into a `custom_field` key with its own hash reference and their display names. Instead, use the internal name of the field directly in the `fields` hash. I don't recall the naming scheme, but those fields have lots of numbers in their names.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Now it's working fine. after adding into fields => {
        project   => { key => 'TIME' },
        issuetype => { name => 'Task' },
        summary   => '20-7-2018 checking field persent or not',
        description => 'test',
        customfield_11197 => 'VIGIL-217'
    },

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing some quote marks in your `fields->custom_field` data structure:

```
# Create the ticket using post function 
my $issue = $jira->POST('/issue', undef, {
    fields => {
        project   => { key => 'TIME' },
        issuetype => { name => 'Task' },
        summary   => '20-7-2018 checking field persent or not',
        description => 'test',
        custom_field => { 'Epic Link' => 'Application Framework'},
    },
});
```

There's also a typo in `summary`, but presumably that doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Stil I am facing same also shared below error log.                              
   JIRA::REST Error[400 - Bad Request]:
- [custom_field] Field 'custom_field' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
 at copy_of_new-jira.pl line 15.
>> /usr/lib64/perl5/Crypt/SSLeay.pm:37: sub Crypt::SSLeay::CTX::DESTROY  { shift->free; }

Comment: Thanks for your support. Now it's working fine. after adding into fields => { project => { key => 'TIME' }, issuetype => { name => 'Task' }, summary => '20-7-2018 checking field persent or not', description => 'test', customfield_11197 => 'VIGIL-217' }